# Dumping a drupal 7 render array to file

Tags: arrays, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a hard time outputting some array data to an XML file. Here's the workflow:

1. Get all relevant data (in this case, a collection of videos and the necessary taxonomy) from the DB.
2. Loop each returned object, cleaning it up a bit (field combinations, etc).
3. Loop each returned object, returning an XML node by use of a template file (templates/module_name_xml_entity.tpl.php).
4. Put all the XML nodes into a wrapper XML template (templates/module_name_xml_wrapper.tpl.php).
5. Save the wrapper (now including the repeated nodes) into a file on the filesystem.

I have been able to complete this workflow if I manually write XML inline (eg: $xml .= ' ' . $data['field'] . '';
That's not optimal however, and I've been asked to use render arrays instead (and to keep my template files within the module).

So, #'s 1, 2, 5 I can figure out (since saving a file is the same). It's #3 that is the real bugger.

My code:

1. The dump from the db query results in an array of video objects (title, thumbnail, tags, etc). I convert that to the following:

> ```
> Array (
>  [#template] => module_name_xml_entry,
>  [#video] => stdClass Object (
>    [title], [thumbnail]....
>  ),
>  [#theme] => module_name_xml_entry,
> )...
> ```

Now here's something interesting: if I dd() the array (there's 990 of them), I see that "#children" and "#printed" has been added automagically, therefore I assume I'm working with a real render array.

1. I then try every darn way I can think of to convert this array into XML. I've tried $xmlOut .= render($theStuffAbove), drupal_render($youguessedit), please_lord_make_it_go($facepalm)... no avail.
2. What I get out is either blank (nothing is in $xmlOut) or the array itself.

Again, I can loop my DB results, convert the result into XML manually (string building mess) and save all that out just fine. It's the using of render arrays that baffles me. Reading "TDGD7" hasn't helped (there's only a few short pages out of 1047 on render arrays), and I'm just not understanding how render arrays can be "rendered."

**Update:**
I forgot to mention I *do* have a module_name_theme(...) function setup:

```
$items = array();
$items['module_name_admin_settings_form'] = array(...);
$items['module_name_xml_wrapper'] = array(
  'variables' => array('videos' => NULL)),
  'template' => 'templates/module_name_xml_wrapper',
);
$items['module_name_xml_entity'] = array(
  'variables' => array('video' => array()),
  'template' => 'templates/module_name_xml_entity',
);
return $items;
```

Comment: To render the array, can't you hand it over to drupal_render(array): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.

Comment: No matter where I pass the array into drupal_render (or even render()) I don't get anything back.

For instance, if I loop over the $videos[] array and try to build up my big XML ($xmlOut[] .= drupal_render($videoItemArray) ) all I get is an empty value array.

Comment: I see your update answer. to render the array, you passed something like drupal_render(array[x]) basically, passing a valid array with elements correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

Ok, so this is odd (swear I'd done this before).

1. Changed template filenames to use dashes instead of underscores (eg: 'templates/module_name_xml_entry.tpl.php -> module-name-xml-entry.tpl.php)
2. Changed reference in the hook_theme() to use the dashed names instead
3. Inside my functions, I used a $variables = array('video' => $video);
4. I called $output[] = theme('module_name_xml_entry', $variables);
5. I used $output in my wrapper (module_name_xml_wrapper) to save to the filesystem.

So the long and short: it looks like cleaning up the theme() function and my hook_theme() made the output work finally.